# React setState hook not updating OUTSIDE a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, react-hooks, setstate

**Update:**

This is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-haze-pi2w8?file=/src/styles.css) example!

I have a textarea component in which I'm preforming validation, line by line:

[image]

The error messages in the UI are a collection of objects which have an id property based on the row the text is on and a message property which will house the error. `e.g. {id: 1, message: 'error message', name: 'text from line'}`

From what I understand you can't set state in a loop as the results are not guaranteed.a

This is the setMessage function which gets the string:

setMessage is being called inside my validation function:

```
function setMessage(data) {
    console.log('data', data);
    console.log("arrFromVariableTypeNameString ", arrFromVariableTypeNameString);
    let allMessages = [...messagesContainer];

    function drop(data, func) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var check = func(data[i]);
            console.log("check ", check);
            if (check) {

                console.log("i + 1 ", i + 1);
                result = data.slice(i, i + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arrFromVariableTypeNameString.length; i++) {

        var match = drop(allMessages, e => e.id === i + 1);

        if (match?.length) {
            match[0] = {
                ...match[0],
                ...{
                    message: data,
                    name: arrFromVariableTypeNameString[i]
                }
            }

            console.log("match ", match);
            console.log("allMessages ", allMessages);

            allMessages = allMessages.map(t1 => ({
                ...t1,
                ...match.find(t2 => {
                    console.log("t2.id === t1.id ", t2.id === t1.id);
                    return t2.id === t1.id
                })
            }))


        } else {
            allMessages.push({
                name: arrFromVariableTypeNameString[i],
                id: i + 1,
                message: data
            })
        }
    }

    setMessagesContainer(allMessages)
}
```

This is the whole component:

```js
export function VariableSetupModal({
  exisitingVariableTypes
}) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState();
  const [variableTypeName, setVariableTypeName] = useState('');
  const [clipboardData, setClipboardData] = useState('')
  const [pasted, setIsPasted] = useState(false)
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState('');
  const [messagesContainer, setMessagesContainer] = useState([]);

  var arrFromVariableTypeNameString = variableTypeName.split('\n');

  useEffect(() => {

        function setMessage(data) {
          console.log('data', data);
          console.log("arrFromVariableTypeNameString ", arrFromVariableTypeNameString);
          let allMessages = [...messagesContainer];

          function drop(data, func) {
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              var check = func(data[i]);
              console.log("check ", check);
              if (check) {

                console.log("i + 1 ", i + 1);
                result = data.slice(i, i + 1);
                break;
              }
            }
            return result;
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < arrFromVariableTypeNameString.length; i++) {

            var match = drop(allMessages, e => e.id === i + 1);

            if (match ? .length) {
              match[0] = { ...match[0],
                ...{
                  message: data,
                  name: arrFromVariableTypeNameString[i]
                }
              }

              console.log("match ", match);
              console.log("allMessages ", allMessages);

              allMessages = allMessages.map(t1 => ({ ...t1,
                ...match.find(t2 => {
                  console.log("t2.id === t1.id ", t2.id === t1.id);
                  return t2.id === t1.id
                })
              }))


            } else {
              allMessages.push({
                name: arrFromVariableTypeNameString[i],
                id: i + 1,
                message: data
              })
            }
          }

          setMessagesContainer(allMessages)
        }

        function validator(variableType) {
          var data = {
            variableType: variableType,
          }

          var rules = {
            variableType: "regex:^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$|min:3|max:20",
          }

          var messages = {
            min: `Enter at least three characters.`,
            max: `Don't exceed more than twenty characters.`,
            regex: `No special characters (but spaces) allowed.`
          }

          validate(data, rules, messages)
            .then(success => {
              console.log('Variable Type Entered correctly.', success)
              setMessage('');
              return
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log('error', error)
              setMessage(error[0].message);
              return
            });
        }

        function checkIfArrayIsUnique(myArray) {
          if (myArray.length === 50) setMessages('Only 50 Variable Types allowed.');
          return myArray.length === new Set(myArray).size;
        }

        arrFromVariableTypeNameString.map((variableType, i, thisArr) => {

          function findDuplicates(uniqueCount) {
            var count = {},
              result = '';
            uniqueCount.forEach((i) => {
              count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
            });
            console.log(count);



            return Object.keys(count).map((k) => {
              if (count[k] > 1) return result.concat(`Variable Type ${k}: appears ${count[k]} times.`)

            }).filter((item) => item !== undefined)

          }

          if (checkIfArrayIsUnique(thisArr)) {
            if (validator(variableType)) {
              return thisArr;
            }
          } else {
            setMessage(findDuplicates(thisArr).map(s => < > {
                  s
                } < br / > < />));
                return;
              }
            })

          return () => {
            setMessagesContainer([])
            console.log("messagesContainer clean up ", messagesContainer);
          }
        }, [variableTypeName])


        const handlePaster = (e) => {
          e.persist()

          setIsPasted(true);
          setClipboardData(e.clipboardData.getData('text'));
        }

        const handleChange = (e) => {
          e.persist()
          var {
            keyCode
          } = e;
          var {
            value
          } = e.target;

          if (keyCode === 13) {
            setVariableTypeName(`${value}\n`);
            return;
          } else if ((pasted == true) && (keyCode == 13)) {
            setVariableTypeName(`${variableTypeName.concat(clipboardData)}\n`);
            setIsPasted(false);
            return;

          } else if ((pasted == true) && (keyCode !== 13)) {
            setVariableTypeName(`${variableTypeName.concat(clipboardData)}`);
            setIsPasted(false);
            return;

          } else {
            setVariableTypeName(`${value}`);
            return;

          }
        }


        return ( <
          div >
          <
          Button className = "button"
          onClick = {
            evt => setIsOpen(true)
          } > Add Variable Types < /Button> <
          div style = {
            {
              display: "none"
            }
          } >

          <
          Modal id = "myModal"
          heading = "Variable Type Configuration"
          description = ""
          userClosable = {
            true
          }
          autoFocus = {
            false
          }

          actionsLeft = { <
            React.Fragment >
            <
            Button display = "text"
            onClick = {
              handleCancel
            } > Cancel < /Button> <
            Button display = "primary"
            onClick = {
              handleSave
            } > Save < /Button> <
            /React.Fragment>
          }

          isOpen = {
            isOpen
          }
          onRequestClose = {
            detail => {
              handleCancel(false);
              setMessagesContainer([])
            }
          } >
          {
            exisitngVarFormatted != "" && < Textbox
            as = "textarea"
            type = "text"
            value = {
              exisitngVarFormatted
            }
            disabled >
            Existing <
            /Textbox>}

            <
            Textbox
            as = "textarea"
            type = "text"
            placeholder = "Variable Types"
            maxLength = "100"
            value = {
              variableTypeName
            }
            onPaste = {
              e => handlePaster(e)
            }
            onChange = {
              e => handleChange(e)
            } >
            To Create <
            /Textbox>


            {
              messagesContainer.map((messageObj, i, arr) => {

                console.log("messageObj ", messageObj);
                return messageObj.message != '' ? ( <
                  p key = {
                    messageObj.id
                  }
                  className = "Messages" > {
                    `Error on line ${i + 1}: ${messageObj.message}`
                  } < /p>
                ) : null
              })
            }


            <
            /Modal> <
            /div> <
            /div >

          );
        }
```

And this is what is having me pulling what's left of my hair out.

In the logs, you can clearly see the objects getting set correctly but then in the UI, the messages are not unique! Line 70

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hover over that `i` with the blue background and read what the tooltip says. Consider using `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable, null, 2))` if the object supports serialization.

Comment: Wow thanks! I never new about that! Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is; what the data should be, what it is, etc. It would be good to have a [mre]. Note I don't see the use of `setState` or hooks in the code right now, so it may be I'm missing something.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I made some edits and included some code of the total component.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Let me explain: 
I am going through and splitting each line in the textarea.
That text should be validated based on a set of rules I have set up.
If it fails I am essentially creating an array of objects to keep track of the errors which are mapped to the line number:
`1: ff`  `{name: `ff`, id: 1, message: 'Min of three characters'}`

Comment: @HereticMonkey For some reason in the loop when I update one line, lets say I test for `special chars` on line two, for example. That cascades to line one as well.

Comment: I don't need a personal explanation. I'm asking these questions to get you to [edit] your question and explain in the question so that more people will understand and can help. I'm not necessarily going to answer this question -- I've got paying work to do :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Gotcha lol :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for suggesting for me to do a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 Not sure why I didn't think of that. Do you think I should re-ask the question?

Comment: It seems like some of your messages apply to a specific line, and others are for the whole list.  Is that correct?  This code is very complicated and can probably be cleaned up quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for responding . Every line should be unique; Like every line should have an object with a message property that has its own unique message from validation if it exists anyway if it doesn’t it would be an empty string and therefore not get rendered to the list of errors.

Comment: As @HereticMonkey suggested I made a code sandbox which is linked. It might be easier to understand with an example and forget everything I wrote.

Comment: I'm looking at it now :)  I think you need a "getLineError" function that finds the errors for a single line.  The part that's tripping me up a bit is that the validation is async.  Otherwise it would basically be `setMessages(lines.map(getLineError))`.

Comment: Does this help? `function setMessageForLine(message, lineNumber) {
    setMessagesContainer(existing => [ ..existing.slice(0, lineNumber), message, ...existing.slice(lineNumber + 1) ])
  }`  You can modify one at a time so long as you base your state off of the previous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230566/discussion-between-linda-paiste-and-antonio-pavicevac-ortiz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for updating a single message is extremely complicated.  It doesn't need to be that hard!  Here's a way to immutably update a single item of the array by index:

```
const setMessageForLine = (message, lineNumber) => {
  setMessagesContainer((existing) => [
    ...existing.slice(0, lineNumber),
    message,
    ...existing.slice(lineNumber + 1)
  ]);
}
```

We use callback notation to get the current value of `messagesContainer` as `existing`.  This prevents updates from interfering with each other if they are done in quick succession and get batched by React.

We can reduce the amount of updates that we need to do to the `messagesContainer` by saving a `ref` of the last set of lines that we validated.  If the text is the same as before then we don't need to validate it again.  But there are some bugs with my implementation of this.

I think it makes the most sense to have every error assigned to a specific line.  So I am changing the "more than 50 lines" and "duplicate" errors to apply to the line that they occur on.  In the first case we just check if the index is `>50`.  For the duplicates, we compare a text against all previous elements.  This means that the first entry of a duplicate pair won't be an error even if it is duplicated later on.  Now that I am thinking about this, that could pose some problems with the `ref` if someone were to edit an existing item at a higher line such that it becomes a duplicate of a lower line, since the lower line won't be re-evaluated.

You are using an `async` validation library so there is both synchronous and asynchronous validation for each line.  The checks that you are doing based on a `regex` and length could easily be made synchronous to make things simpler.

---

With current async validation

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { validate } from "indicative/validator";

export function TextArea({ onSave }) {
  const [variableTypeName, setVariableTypeName] = useState("");
  const [clipboardData, setClipboardData] = useState("");
  const [pasted, setIsPasted] = useState(false);
  const [messagesContainer, setMessagesContainer] = useState([]);

  // don't need to validate the same text more than once
  const lastCheckedLines = useRef([]);

const setMessageForLine = useCallback(
  (message, lineNumber) => {
    setMessagesContainer((existing) => [
      ...existing.slice(0, lineNumber),
      message,
      ...existing.slice(lineNumber + 1)
    ]);
  },
  [setMessagesContainer]
);

  const getLineError = useCallback(
    (text, index, all) => {
      // if too many lines
      if (index >= 50) {
        return "Only 50 Variable Types allowed.";
      }

      // blank lines will show up as duplicates of each other
      if (text.length === 0) {
        return "No empty lines";
      }

      // check if this line is the same as any of the previous
      const duplicateOf = all.slice(0, index).findIndex((v) => v === text);
      if (duplicateOf !== -1) {
        return `Duplicate of line ${duplicateOf + 1}`;
      }
    },
    []
  );

  const asyncValidateLine = useCallback(
    (text, index) => {
      var data = {
        variableType: text
      };

      var rules = {
        variableType: "regex:^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$|min:3|max:20"
      };

      var messages = {
        min: `Enter at least three characters.`,
        max: `Don't exceed more than twenty characters.`,
        regex: `No special characters (but spaces) allowed.`
      };

      validate(data, rules, messages)
        .then((success) => {
          console.log("Variable Type Entered correctly.", success);
          setMessageForLine("", index);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error", error);
          setMessageForLine(error[0].message, index);
        });
    },
    [setMessageForLine]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const lineTexts = variableTypeName.split("\n");

    // remove extra lines when deleting
    setMessagesContainer((existing) =>
      existing.length > lineTexts.length
        ? existing.slice(0, lineTexts.length)
        : existing
    );

    lineTexts.forEach((text, i) => {
      // only check if we have a new text
      if (text !== lastCheckedLines.current[i]) {
        console.log(`evaluating line ${i + 1}`);
        const error = getLineError(text, i, lineTexts);
        if (error) {
          setMessageForLine(error, i);
        } else {
          asyncValidateLine(text, i);
        }
      }
    });

    lastCheckedLines.current = lineTexts;
  }, [variableTypeName, getLineError, asyncValidateLine, setMessageForLine, setMessagesContainer]);

  const handlePaster = (e) => {
    e.persist();

    setIsPasted(true);
    setClipboardData(e.clipboardData.getData("text"));
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    var { keyCode } = e;
    var { value } = e.target;

    if (keyCode === 13) {
      setVariableTypeName(`${value}\n`);
      return;
    } else if (pasted === true && keyCode === 13) {
      setVariableTypeName(`${variableTypeName.concat(clipboardData)}\n`);
      setIsPasted(false);
      return;
    } else if (pasted === true && keyCode !== 13) {
      setVariableTypeName(`${variableTypeName.concat(clipboardData)}`);
      setIsPasted(false);
      return;
    } else {
      setVariableTypeName(`${value}`);
      return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        placeholder="Variable Types"
        maxLength={100}
        value={variableTypeName}
        onPaste={(e) => handlePaster(e)}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      />

      {messagesContainer.map((message, i, arr) => {
        console.log("message ", message);
        return message ? (
          <p key={i} className="Messages">{`Error on line ${
            i + 1
          }: ${message}`}</p>
        ) : null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextArea onSave={console.log} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Simple version -- all synchronous and no `ref` comparison

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export function TextArea({ onSave }) {
  const [variableTypeName, setVariableTypeName] = useState("");
  const [clipboardData, setClipboardData] = useState("");
  const [pasted, setIsPasted] = useState(false);
  const [messagesContainer, setMessagesContainer] = useState([]);

  const getLineError = useCallback(
    (text, index, all) => {
      // if too many lines
      if (index >= 50) {
        return "Only 50 Variable Types allowed.";
      }

      if (text.length < 3) {
        return `Enter at least three characters.`;
      }

      if (text.length > 20) {
        return `Don't exceed more than twenty characters.`;
      }

      if (!text.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/)) {
        return `No special characters (but spaces) allowed.`;
      }

      // check if this line is the same as any of the previous
      const duplicateOf = all.slice(0, index).findIndex((v) => v === text);
      if (duplicateOf !== -1) {
        return `Duplicate of line ${duplicateOf + 1}`;
      }

      return "";
    },
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const lineTexts = variableTypeName.split("\n");
    setMessagesContainer(lineTexts.map(getLineError));
  }, [variableTypeName, getLineError, setMessagesContainer]);

  const handlePaster = (e) => {
    e.persist();

    setIsPasted(true);
    setClipboardData(e.clipboardData.getData("text"));
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    var { keyCode } = e;
    var { value } = e.target;

    if (keyCode === 13) {
      setVariableTypeName(`${value}\n`);
      return;
    } else if (pasted === true && keyCode === 13) {
      setVariableTypeName(`${variableTypeName.concat(clipboardData)}\n`);
      setIsPasted(false);
      return;
    } else if (pasted === true && keyCode !== 13) {
      setVariableTypeName(`${variableTypeName.concat(clipboardData)}`);
      setIsPasted(false);
      return;
    } else {
      setVariableTypeName(`${value}`);
      return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        placeholder="Variable Types"
        maxLength={100}
        value={variableTypeName}
        onPaste={(e) => handlePaster(e)}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      />

      {messagesContainer.map((message, i, arr) => {
        console.log("message ", message);
        return message ? (
          <p key={i} className="Messages">{`Error on line ${
            i + 1
          }: ${message}`}</p>
        ) : null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextArea onSave={console.log} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-tereshkova-4bmrs?file=/src/App.tsx:0-2689)

Comment: Hi Linda, Thank you so much for your thorough explanation!!!!  As you can see from my implementation lot of brute force things going on. However I really wanted to get into useCallbacks! I was reading up on them today, as a matter of fact. I think I got the gist of it. But they're helpful because they prevent creation of function objects between renders?

Comment: That's exactly right :) I am using them here because I want the `useEffect` dependencies to be exhaustive. Meaning that every variable used inside the `useEffect` should be a dependency.  If you want to use a function as a `useEffect` dependency then you need to use `useCallback` or else the effect would re-run on every render because the function would be a new instance on every render.  If you didn't use `useCallback` then you would have to omit the functions from the dependency array, which honestly would be fine except that eslint might complain.

Comment: Thank you! And I saw the `useRef` (that is really cool!) I tried something with it but I think I was getting to a point where everything was getting hard to reason about.

Comment: I suppose things will become easier with time and experience. Like with everything!

Comment: Honestly I would go with the "simple version".  The `useRef` seemed like a good idea but it adds complications and edge cases that need to be addressed.  Whereas if you recompute every time it's guaranteed to be correct.